# Stem plot in r question

Tags: r, data-visualization

Why is is that when I do the stem function in R, the stem and leaf values don't correspond to the data points? When I do scale=2, then it works.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably more of a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question than a CV question, because it focuses on how R works and why, rather than the statistical aspects of stem and leaf plots.  Nonetheless...

The way the function is coded is designed to shorten the length of the output, so that it better fits in the console.  Few people, I believe, find that terribly helpful, or at least I don't.  Just always remember to start with `scale=2`, and you may have to play with it further or adjust the `width` argument.  Also, know that there is a fancier version [stem.leaf()](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/Rcmdr/html/stem.leaf.html) in [Rcmdr](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/).